# What versions of PowerShell, SqlCmlet, and SQL database engines are compatible?

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I need to work with numerous versions of SQL Server 2008R2 to current. I'm trying to learn and do more with PowerShell. So far, I have determined the following based on research. Can anyone please verify these and also add any specific details about backwards compatibility? Any additional help is appreciated.

```
SQL Server 2008R2 - PowerShell V2 (?) - SQLServerCmdletSnapin and SQLServerProviderSnapin
SQL Server 2012 and 2014 (?) - PowerShell v3 - SQLPS (load with Import-Module)
SQL Server 2016 and later - PowerShell v5 and later - SqlServer (load with Install-Module)
```

**New information below this point
I guess what I am asking is can I use the SQLServer with PowerShell versions prior to v5 and SQL versions prior to SQL 2016, or am I stuck with the commands that were included in SQLPS?

Or, if I am on Powershell v5 and SQL 2016, and write a script to manage SQL instances and databases, can I give it to people running SQL 2012 and have it work?

Can I use cmdlets like Add-RoleMember found in the SqlServer module, but not the SQLPS module be used, as long as I have them load the new module first, or does the new module only work on the newer SQL versions?

Also, is there a minimum version of PowerShell that supports the SqlServer module?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking here. What version of Powershell you can use isn't related to the SQL Server version, it's related to the OS. I've used Powershell 7.0 to connect to SQL Server 2008 and 2017 (and others between).

Comment: The ADO.NET code that these modules use under the covers is highly compatible -- backwards *and* forwards. Only when you attempt to use features that are truly not present (like `DATETIME2` support under .NET 2.0 or Always On failover groups) will you conceivably run into trouble, but you'd need some pretty old and unsupported configurations before that's relevant. The only truly unsupported scenario is connecting to SQL Server 2000 or earlier under PowerShell Core -- .NET Core has dropped support for these versions and it will refuse to connect.

Comment: @Larnu - I added some additional questions that may help you understand what I was looking for.

Comment: @JeroenMostert - thank you for this information.  If I'm understanding you correctly, I can write powershell scripts that will work version to version. Is it also true that I can load the SqlServer module to work with any version of SQL 2008R2 and later?  I'm not looking at anything earlier than this.

Comment: Yes, the `SqlServer` module (as long as you can get it to load on your version of PowerShell, I don't think 2.0 supports it, but I've never tested that) will connect to any version of SQL Server 2005 or later. There may be corner cases where compatibility wasn't completely tested so the module may try and fail to access features that aren't present on old versions without checking first, but basic stuff like executing queries will absolutely work, and most cmdlets will eventually boil down to executing T-SQL commands anyway (or XMLA, in the case of Analysis Services).

Comment: Thank you @JeroenMostert - another stupid question.  Can you tell me how to accept your answer as the best?  I don't see a button for that and I'm new posting here.